# How do we dynamically add columns in a datatable

Tags: visualforce, datatable

I am trying to build a VF page which dynamically displays the datatable. The fields to be displayed are not known, they need to taken from a custom setting.

Here is what i am trying to achieve

I have a custom setting which has field names(API names) of columns that need to be displayed in the data table

I also have a list of a quotelineitem which also uses this custom setting to get the records. The issue i am facing is how do we display the columns in datatable as we would only know the field name at run time.

In the code below to display account name i would need to specify `<apex:outputText value="{!account.name}"/>`  in the VF page, but since i really dont know which fields would be displayed is there a way we can dynamically populate the field names.

I am not stuck with datatable, i am open to any other way to dynamically display the fields

```
            <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>

        <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>

        <apex:outputText value="{!account.name}"/>

   </apex:column>
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf.htm and http://devendranatani.blogspot.de/2011/05/dynamic-binding-salesforce.html

Comment: Iterate over a Map of <ApiName, Label> using apex:repeat which renders apex:columns for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visualforce allows you to use brackets (`[]`) that treats data like a map.  For sObjects in a visualforce page they're treated like a map of field values with api names for keys.  So you just need to loop over the api names from your custom setting.  The example below uses a page block, but you can use pretty much any output structure you want.

**Example**

```
<apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!records}" var="record">
    <apex:repeat value="{!fieldAPINames}" var="fieldAPIName">
      <apex:column value="{!record[fieldAPIName]}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using [Fieldset](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=fields_about_field_sets.htm&siteLang=en_US) to let your users configure the visible fields instead of using your own Custom Setting? This is a more native solution to what I believe is your use case. There is a good example how to use it in Visualforce [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm). You can also use **apex:outputField** to bind to the columns and display the values, which will leverage the native Visualforce formatting for various field types, currency, date, time etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post, talks about dynamically adding columns to VF table: http://www.cldpartners.com/blog/dynamic-columns-salesforce-visualforce-tables/

Comment: You may want to summarize the process in case the content you linked to ever goes away.

Comment: The link went away :(